# Unable to start main activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Here is my app file. Can you please tell what is causing my app to crash and what can be done to fix this?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kBmPCesA-hsu44lB2ugnBF-T_2-_JZbE

Here is what the run tab shows, the logcat shows no errors. It seems like the error occurs initiating the onCreate method but i tried adding a breakpoint before that method. Even then the app crashes.

Here is the MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.aboutme

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.example.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

         binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

//        findViewById<Button>(R.id.submit_button).setOnClickListener {
//            showName(it)
//        }

         binding.doneButton.setOnClickListener {
            addNickname(it)
         }
    }

    private fun addNickname(view:View){
        binding.apply {
            nicknameText.text = nicknameEdit.text
            invalidateAll()
            nicknameEdit.visibility = View.GONE
            doneButton.visibility = View.GONE
            nicknameText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        //Hide the keyboard.
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

Here is the strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">AboutMe</string>
    <string name="name">Waleed</string>
    <string name="yellow_star">Yellow Star</string>
    <string name="bio">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,\n\n
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \n
        Mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Quis vel eros donec ac. Tellus cras\n
        adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas. Dui id ornare arcu odio. Venenatis\n
        tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Nulla \n
        facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus. Malesuada fames ac turpis \n
        egestas maecenas. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a. \n
        In mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida.

    \n\n Mtellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Nulla \n
        facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus. Malesuada fames ac turpis \n
        egestas maecenas. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a. \n
        In mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida..</string>
    <string name="hint">Enter your name here</string>
    <string name="Submit">Done</string>
</resources>
```

And the dimens.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="text_size">20sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="small_padding">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="layout_padding">20dp</dimen>
    <item name="line_spacing" type="dimen" format="float">1.2</item>
</resources>
```

Here is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/layout_padding"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/layout_padding">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_text"
            style="@style/name_style"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/layout_padding"
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nickname_edit"
            style="@style/name_style"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hint"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/done_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#8BC34A"
            android:shadowRadius="@dimen/layout_padding"
            android:text="@string/Submit"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nickname_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/star_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_padding"
            android:contentDescription="@string/yellow_star"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/layout_padding"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/bio_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bio_text"
                style="@style/name_style"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="@dimen/line_spacing"
                android:text="@string/bio" />
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aboutme, PID: 11533
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aboutme/com.example.aboutme.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33 in com.example.aboutme:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #33 in com.example.aboutme:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class Button
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3333)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2043)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7464)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:955)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33 in com.example.aboutme:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #33 in com.example.aboutme:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class Button
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33 in com.example.aboutme:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class Button
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20.0dip"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
        at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getFloat(TypedArray.java:475)
        at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:4036)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1076)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:166)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:141)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:72)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:68)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:192)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:111)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1059)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:303)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
        at com.example.aboutme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7990)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7979)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3308)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2043)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7464)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:955)
```

Comment: edit code with xml also

Comment: post the relevant code with your question.

Comment: I posted the code. Please check

Comment: Can you add your styles.xml and dimens.xml?

Comment: @Muhammadwaleed which device/phone are you using to test it? or are you testing it on emulator?

Comment: `android:shadowRadius="@dimen/layout_padding"` – This line in the `<Button>` is the issue. That expects a plain float with no dimension, so you can't use that `dimen` there.

Comment: I was running on Pixel 2. Yes i checked. Exactly this line ```android:shadowRadius="@dimen/layout_padding" ```-- was causing the issue. The app runs fine now. Thanks alot! Can you please tell how to debug such runtime errors?! I am having a hard time debugging my app. I can't ask here everytime i encounter such an error and the official documentation is too difficult to understand. How can a beginner learn to debug?

Comment: Well, if you look through the stack trace, you'll see that it's failing while inflating a `Button`, and you only have one in that layout. The `shadowRadius` requirement, though, is just something that I learned at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your project.

In your logs says:

```
InflateException: Binary XML file line #33 in com.example.aboutme:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #33 in com.example.aboutme:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class Button
```

So the error is with your Button.

Exactly, the error is the attribute shadowRadius because you are using the 20dp dimens, but the Android documentation says that:

```
May be a floating point value, such as "1.2".
```

If you change the 20dp dimens by 20 then you can compile your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This was causing the issue!